# How to get the element from a excel which contains multiple HTML Tags?

Tags: html, excel, vba

Now I am having a excel file that full of HTML tags, which are stored as strings like:

```
< Productname= " ABC " label= " CDE " show_ always= " 1" length-threshold= " 1" truncate- threshold= " 10" max- value-width= " 10" value- extension= " . . . " delimiter= " | " >
< Productname= " XYZ " label= " XYZ " show_ always= " 1" length-threshold= " 1" truncate- threshold= " 10" max- value-width= " 10" value- extension= " . . . " delimiter= " | " >
< Productname= " JKL " label= " JKL " show_ always= " 1" length-threshold= " 1" truncate- threshold= " 10" max- value-width= " 10" value- extension= " . . . " delimiter= " | " >
```

And I would like to extract the different values in the code, and present them as follows:

```
       Productname  label   show_always length-threshold value- extension ...
           ABC       CDE        1             1             . . .
```

1, I though of using the "=" as a separator, but the strings, which is the name of the variable, have different lengths and they are strings instead of variables in the documents. Therefore I do not have idea how can I accruately get the value. Is there any way that I can get the value in fromt and behind the value accruately?

2, Besides of this althorigm, is there any better way to solve the problem, without directly scrawing from the site?

Looking forward to your answer and many thanks!

Comment: Use DOM traversing or web Scrapping, it depends on the target's structure. You can also use Json parsing. And Regex is used to make fine adjustments after parsing.

Comment: Are those `<` and `>` actually part of the content?  That's not valid HTML or XML...

Answer (score 0):

You should really use xslt. It's a language to perfom magic in several ways:
https://www.google.se/search?q=excel+xslt

Comment: How would you use xslt on that? It's not valid XML